# Need Some Guidance to Optimize Reporting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

My team maintains an app/database that processes millions of records each week. The process is fairly simple:

- Send Notifications to contacts for various campaigns
- Write the contact_id, campaign_id, message_id, created_at, updated_at to a log when a notification is sent
- Read the record count for each notificationID/notification_messageID and display that to the user in a report.

The writing and reading process to the log takes an exceptionally long time and we're looking for a way to optimize it.

The write statement occurs when a notification is sent. It batches the insert for 20 records in one query. Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO `contact_notification_logs` (`id`, `contact_id`, `campaign_id`, 
`message_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `is_reset`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, '1', '1', '1', '2019-01-23 20:16:21', '2019-01-23 20:16:24', 
'0'),
```

There are two read statements that occurs:

1. This one is pretty simple, it runs on a page where all campaigns are listed and displays the current count of notifications sent for TODAY:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM contact_notification_logs 
WHERE DATE(created_at) = '[current date]'
```

That one, while simple, still takes a long time to execute.

2. The second read statement is a bit more complex because it is built into a reporting tool on the app where users can specify params, but the root 'select count' is the same.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM contact_email_logs 
WHERE DATE(created_at) > '2018-12-23'
AND DATE(created_at) < '2019-01-23'
AND campaign_id = 27
AND message_id = 133
```

A couple of extra points:

1. The data needs to be able to be pulled in real time. Meaning if I want to check the count for all notification campaigns at this exact point in time, I can. So the query runs to count all at that time.
2. The contact_notification_logs has 28,740,585 records in it.

Am I missing something obvious here that will allow us to optimize the run times for these queries?

Answer (score 0):

for the first read query:
Do you have an index on created_at field ?

for the second read query:
Do you have an index based on three fields: created_at, campaign_id and message_id ?

If not, take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response.

We have indexes on all fields, but the date fields. Not sure why - I'm checking that.

Answer (score 0):

**Inefficient date range leads to checking too many rows**

```
WHERE DATE(created_at) > '2018-12-23'
  AND DATE(created_at) < '2019-01-23'
  AND campaign_id = 27
  AND message_id = 133
```

Don't write date comparisons that way.  It cannot use an index involving `created_at` because it is hidden in a function call (`DATE()`).  Instead:

```
WHERE created_at >= '2018-12-23'
  AND created_at  < '2018-12-23' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If that `DATE()` stuff is generated by a 3rd party package, you need to abandon it.

**Lack of suitable index**

Then... you need a composite index:

```
INDEX(campaign_id, message_id,   -- in either order
      created_at)                -- after those
```

**For simply "today"**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact_notification_logs 
    WHERE created_at >= '[current date]'
      AND created_at  < '[current date]' + INTERVAL 1 DAY

INDEX(created_at)  -- the previous index will not help for _this_ query
```

**Need Summary Table**

With 28M rows, you may find that my suggestions above are not sufficient.  To get another 10x improvement, [*build and maintain a Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).  Suggest using days, not weeks or months as the resolution.

**Others**

Don't use `COUNT(id)` unless you need to check whether `id` is `NULL`.  Instead, use the common pattern:  `COUNT(*)`.

If `created_at` is type `DATE`, the original query is one month, minus one day.  If it is `DATETIME`, then it is missing midnight of the starting date.  With my code, it works correctly regardless of the datatype.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.